# $\lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt{x^2 + 2x + 1} $

Tags: limits, radicals

I get $\lim_{x\to\infty} {x+1} = \infty $
But I am wrong. Why?

With L'Hospital, I get $$ \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{x^2 + 2x + 1} \cdot (2x+2) = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{1} 2 = 1$$

Comment: You applied L'Hôpital's rule incorrectly.

Comment: I'd like to say how much the notation $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1}2$ *bothers* me! :-P

Comment: I am afraid you confused $\infty$ and $0$ (not counting that you *did not* apply L'Hospital at all).

Comment: The question is not in a form where L'Hopital's rule can be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x\geqslant-1$, then $\sqrt{x^2+2x+1}=x+1$ and therefore, yes,$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{x^2+2x+1}=\lim_{x\to\infty}x+1=\infty.$$

And you cannot apply L'Hopital's rule, since you do not have an indeterminate form here.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is 
$$
\begin{gathered}
  \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } \sqrt {x^2  + 2x + 1}  =  \hfill \\
   \hfill \\
   = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } \sqrt {\left( {x + 1} \right)^2 }  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } \left| {x + 1} \right| =  + \infty  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
De L'Hospital's Rule is for limits of the type
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } \frac{{f(x)}}
{{g(x)}}
$$
with 
$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } f(x) = \infty 
$ and $
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } g(x) = \infty 
$
under suitable hypothesis. This is not your case

Answer (score 0):

Without L'Hopital's rule you can rewrite:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{x^2 + 2x + 1} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{(x + 1)^2} = \lim_{x \to \infty} |x+1|$$

Since $x$ is a large value, you can omit absolute value: $\lim_{x \to \infty} (x+1)=\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

L'Hopital applies to the indeterminate forms $\infty/\infty$ or $0/0$.

In this case we have simply

$$\sqrt{x^2 + 2x + 1}\ge x\to \infty$$